# gradle error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/api/specs/Spec when trying to run unit-tests

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle based spring boot project. When I would like to run the tests an error message like this appears:

```
gradle-resources-test:my-project.my-module.test: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/api/specs/Spec
```

What can I do to find out more about the problem?